# Book about the whole operation of the computers

Tags: history, books

I was wondering, If there is a book about whole operation of a Computer. I mean since the operation of software, programming languages (high and low level) and  drivers until the deep physics explanation of the operation of hardware like microprocessors, transistors and the other devices.

Something like since the Bigger thing until the more tiny thing.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for [this](http://www.nand2tetris.org/).

Comment: [Code](http://www.charlespetzold.com/code/)